# onClick doesn't work while trying to render: reactjs, basic API fetch

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to do a basic API fetch and show that information onClick using a button called GENERATE. All it should do for now is show the first url in the json I receive.

Once that is achieved, I want it to show the next url on each click.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { ThemeProvider, createToolkitTheme } from 'internaltools/theme';
import { AppHeader } from 'internaltools/app-header';


const LIGHT_THEME = createToolkitTheme('light');
const DARK_THEME = createToolkitTheme('dark');
const API = 'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=';
const DEFAULT_QUERY = 'redux';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        hits: [],
        isLoading: false,
        error: null,
      };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    fetch(API + DEFAULT_QUERY)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Something went wrong with the API...');
        }
      })
      .then(data => this.setState({ hits: data.hits[0], isLoading: false }))
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }


  render() {
    const { hits, isLoading, error } = this.state;

    return (
        <>
          <button onClick={hits.url}>GENERATE</button>
        </>
    );
  }
}
```

Please help me find out why my button doesn't work. And how do I iterate over the urls on each click, i.e. show the next url from the json on each click. Thanks.

Comment: What is the button supposed to do? What should happen when you click it?

Comment: onClick should have a function instead of a property where you will write logic to iterate over the urls.

Comment: where do you show the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an onClick handler function to update a state value.

Here's a codesandbox that stores the hits array in state along with a current index, and a handler that simply increments the index.

[image: Edit eloquent-mccarthy-ftfcs]

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a function name to your onClick handler. Then in that function you can access the data you wanted.

```
enter code here
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { ThemeProvider, createToolkitTheme } from 'internaltools/theme';
import { AppHeader } from 'internaltools/app-header';


const LIGHT_THEME = createToolkitTheme('light');
const DARK_THEME = createToolkitTheme('dark');
const API = 'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=';
const DEFAULT_QUERY = 'redux';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    hits: [],
    isLoading: false,
    error: null,
    hitsCount: 0
  };
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({ isLoading: true });

  fetch(API + DEFAULT_QUERY)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong with the API...');
      }
    })
    .then(data => 
       this.setState({ hits: data.hits, hitsCount: 0 ,isLoading: false 
    }))
     .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
    }

  handleClick(){
     this.setState(prevState => ({ hitsCount: prevState.hitsCount + 1 
     }));
  }

  render() {
    const { hits, hitsCount, isLoading, error } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
         <div>
           count: {hitsCount}
           url: {hits[hitsCount].url}
         </div>
         <button onClick={this.handleClick}>GENERATE</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't iterate over hits data at all, it just logs the first url.

Comment: I was trying to show, that the main problem was not passing function name to the onClick handler. Thanks for your notice. I'm editing now.

Answer (score 0):

Consider This:

Read through the comments in the code to get the updates.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        hits: [],
        currentHit: 0, //add a state currentHit to hold the url that is displayed by now
        isLoading: false,
        error: null,
      };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    fetch(API + DEFAULT_QUERY)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Something went wrong with the API...');
        }
      })
      .then(data => this.setState({ hits: data.hits, isLoading: false })) //Make hits array holding all the hits in the response instead of only the first one
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      currentHit: prevState.currentHit + 1,
    }));
  }


  render() {
    const { hits, isLoading, error, currentHit } = this.state;
    // pass the handleClick function as a callback for onClick event in the button.
    return (
        <>
          <p>{hits[currentHit].url}<p/>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>GENERATE</button>
        </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code, on each click next url will be shown.
[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-lumiere-qmbo6)

handleChange method can work if you want to append the url from array as well. Or you could just increment the index in this function.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    index: 0
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users")
      .then(response => {
        if (response) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error("Something went wrong with the API...");
        }
      })
      .then(data => this.setState({ data: data.data }))
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error }));
  }
  handleChange = () => {
    let i =
      this.state.index < this.state.data.length ? (this.state.index += 1) : 0;
    this.setState({ index: i });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <span>
          {this.state.data.length && this.state.data[this.state.index].avatar}
        </span>
        <button onClick={this.handleChange}>GENERATE</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```